# How to use repository folder as wiki content

Tags: github

I have a public repository on github. one of the subfolders contains an html site.

Can i use the root html page as the root of the repository wiki? And if so, how?

Preferably, i'd like to point the wiki to the html folder rather than having to create a copy of the folder and put it in some 'special' folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your wiki in the gitHub repo:

```
https://github.com/user/yourProject.wiki.git
```

It will got with https://github.com/user/yourProject

If you want to see it right in `yourProject` repo, you could reference it as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

But in any case, you wouldn't store html, as describe in "[Making GitHub More Open: Git-backed Wikis](https://github.com/blog/699-making-github-more-open-git-backed-wikis)". You would store text page in Markdown syntax ([with relative links too!](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files)).

Comment: Are you saying its not possible to store html in wiki, or just not advisable?

Comment: @LeeBurrows I never seen a wiki on GitHub with HTML, I always assumed a Merkdown content.