# Clean-up/refactor Github wiki

Tags: git, github, refactoring, wiki

We are using the a GitHub wiki for all our in-company documentation. As this got messy with time we would like to do a clean-up. However we find neither git nor the GitHub front end very convenient to do so.

Are there any tools available to facilitate such a process which I've missed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to do said cleanup in a local copy of that GitHub wiki, [since it is a Git repo in itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745471/6309):

```
git clone https://github.com/<user>/<yourProject>.wiki.git
```

Once cloned locally, you can clean it up, modifying / moving files, and then push it back.

Comment: Thank you. I aware of this possibility but I do not know how to continue from here. Using a normal editor with a bunch of .md files is not working very well in my experience.